# PNG file is corrupt when reading back from SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, bitmapimage

I have a database program that stores images to the SQL DB and reads them back to be displayed in a WPF application. if i use Jpeg images it works fine, but if i use PNG images, which i wanted to use to try and keep the transparency ( which disappears anyway when stored ) most of the images come back corrupt.

this is the image that has been selected

[image]

i then save it to the db, and add the image the listview

[image]

then if i close the application and reload it, it pulls the image back from the db, you can see that it is corrupt in the listview

[image]

and then when i select it, the image control also shows the corrupted image

[image]

i am storing the image in code using a BitmapImage object, and use this to set the image.source, and also convert this to a byte[] for storing into the image field in the database.

i convert the bitmapimage to a Byte[] with the following line

```
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", ImageToByteArray(productImage.ProductImage));
```

and these are the functions to convert to and from a bitmapimage

```
        private static BitmapImage BuildImage(byte[] image)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(image);
        bitmap.StreamSource = mem;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        //bitmap.Freeze();

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static byte[] ImageToByteArray(BitmapImage image)
    {
        byte[] data;
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            encoder.Save(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return data;

    }
```

works fine with Jpegs, but then i have the white background to the images.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which programming language and DBMS are you using?

Comment: I suggest using varBinary as datatype in SQL and put it inside a stream in C# and convert it to String base64 ;)

Comment: An image is simply a BLOB to SQL Server. It does not affect or modify the data in any way so the problem is how you store and read it...

Comment: Jpeg doesn't support transparency.

Comment: i am using c# as the language and SQL Express 2014 as the DB. i did think that once it was stored as a byte[] it should be fine, so maybe its the conversion in c#, the image is displayed as an image and i set the .source to be the BitmapImage, when reading back, i convert the source back to a bitmapimage, storedImage = img.source as BitmapImage... i will try changing the database type to varBinary, but i am not sure that will make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

"JpegBitmapEncoder" is a large clue. Surely you'd want  ["PNGBitmapEncoder"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder(v=vs.110).aspx)...?

Answer (score 1):

As personal preference I would change your SQL data column to varbinary(MAX) and use stream and BinaryReader objects to upload the file.

However I think your issue is you are not using PngBitmapEncoder for the PNG you are using the JpegBitmapEncoder irrespective of filetype.

Hope this helps.